# Storport Virtual Miniport Driver stopping on AdapterControl

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, driver, kmdf

Why my StorPort Virtual Miniport Driver (KMDF) stops working after it's **AdapterControl** function is first called?

Currently, the following is happening after the driver is implemented (WinDbg):

- DriverEntry is called. No errors.
- HwFindAdapter is called. No errors.
- HwInitialize is called. No errors.
- HwStartIo is called. No errors. Parameter `PSCSI_REQUEST_BLOCK` ("SRB") -> Function is `SRB_FUNCTION_STORAGE_REQUEST_BLOCK` (this is OK for me because in the HwFindAdapter routine, I defined `PPORT_CONFIGURATION_INFORMATION` -> SrbType to equal `SRB_TYPE_STORAGE_REQUEST_BLOCK`).
- AdapterControl is called. No errors. Parameter `SCSI_ADAPTER_CONTROL_TYPE` is called with ControlType `ScsiQuerySupportedControlTypes` (as is default behavior according to MS documentation for the first call).
- And that's it. No more calls, and I couldn't find anything related in EventLog. As far as I know, at this point the StorPort sould make another call to my driver's `AdapterControl` routine and "ask" me to define a device.

--

Please note that the following is not the actual full code, but rather a structural overview:

```
DriverEntry (
  _In_ PVOID      DriverObject,
  _In_ PVOID      RegistryPath
)
{
  HW_INITIALIZATION_DATA initdata = { 0 }
  
  initdata.HwFindAdapter =          HwFindAdapter;
  initdata.HwInitialize =           HwInitialize;
  initdata.HwAdapterControl =       AdapterControl;
  initdata.HwResetBus =             HwResetBus;
  initdata.HwStartIo =              HwStartIo;
  initdata.HwFreeAdapterResources = HwFreeAdapterResources;
  
  initdata.AdapterInterfaceType = Internal;
  initdata.MultipleRequestPerLu = TRUE;
  initdata.PortVersionFlags = 0;
  
  status = StorPortInitialize(
    DriverObject,
    RegistryPath,
    &initdata,
    NULL
  );
  
  return status;
}
```

|

```
HwFindAdapter (AdapterExtension, HwContext, BusInformation, ArgumentString, ConfigInfo, Reserved3)
{
  //ConfigInfo is referenced to PPORT_CONFIGURATION_INFORMATION in the parameters above.
  
  ConfigInfo->AlignmentMask = FILE_BYTE_ALIGNMENT;
  ConfigInfo->NumberOfBuses = 1
  ConfigInfo->CachesData = FALSE;
  ConfigInfo->MapBuffers = STOR_MAP_ALL_BUFFERS_INCLUDING_READ_WRITE;
  ConfigInfo->MaximumNumberOfTargets = 255;
  ConfigInfo->SrbType = SRB_TYPE_STORAGE_REQUEST_BLOCK;
  ConfigInfo->AddressType = STORAGE_ADDRESS_TYPE_BTL8;
  ConfigInfo->SynchronizationModel = StorSynchronizeFullDuplex;
  ConfigInfo->HwMSInterruptRoutine = NULL;
  ConfigInfo->InterruptSynchronizationMode = InterruptSupportNone;
  ConfigInfo->VirtualDevice = TRUE;
  ConfigInfo->DumpMode = DUMP_MODE_RESUME;
  ConfigInfo->MaxNumberOfIO = 100;
  ConfigInfo->BusResetHoldTime = 0;
  ConfigInfo->FeatureSupport = 0x7f;
  
  return SP_RETURN_FOUND;
}
```

HwInitialize is there but does nothing except returning STATUS_SUCCESS.

|

```
HwStartIo (
  _In_    PVOID                               DeviceExtension,
  _In_    PSCSI_REQUEST_BLOCK                 Srb
)
{
  //Currently does nothing with data, as is not needed for now.
  
  StorPortNotification(RequestComplete, DeviceExtension, Srb);
  
  return TRUE;
}
```

|

```
AdapterControl (
  _In_    PVOID                               DeviceExtension,
  _In_    SCSI_ADAPTER_CONTROL_TYPE           ControlType,
  _In_    PVOID                               Parameters
)
{
  PSCSI_SUPPORTED_CONTROL_TYPE_LIST controlTypeList;
  
  switch (ControlType)
  {
    case ScsiQuerySupportedControlTypes:
      controlTypeList = (PSCSI_SUPPORTED_CONTROL_TYPE_LIST)Parameters; // get pointer to control type list
      
      controlTypeList->SupportedTypeList[ScsiQuerySupportedControlTypes] = TRUE;
      controlTypeList->SupportedTypeList[ScsiStopAdapter] = TRUE;
      controlTypeList->SupportedTypeList[ScsiRestartAdapter] = TRUE;
      controlTypeList->SupportedTypeList[ScsiSetBootConfig] = TRUE;
      
    //referenced cases are defined but not relevant for now.
  }
  
  return ScsiAdapterControlSuccess;
}
```

HwFreeAdapterResources is there but does nothing, and returns nothing because it is a VOID.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found out what was wrong.

HwStartIo was called, but with value `PSCSI_REQUEST_BLOCK->Function == "SRB_FUNCTION_PNP"`.

This indicates an error on any function called beforehand, in my case I had a wrong return code set (Function HwInitialize: I returned `"STATUS_SUCCESS" (0xL) instead of "TRUE" (0x0)`.)

In normal operation, upon first initialization, `PSCSI_REQUEST_BLOCK->Function` should equal `"SRB_FUNCTION_EXECUTE_SCSI"` to gather SCSI Bus-, Target- and LUN information.